# jsp: expand / collapse only works for first element in a list

Tags: jquery, jsp

I'm new to jsp's.
I'm trying to expand / collapse each "Value Code" in a List.

When each Value Code expands it should have a table of Value Item rows.

The code works fine when I click on the first Value Code in the list. 
However, every other Value Code that I try to expand always expands the first Value Code in the list and not the one that I clicked on.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

```
<%
List<ValueBean> vBeanList = cart.getValueList();
for (int index = 0; index<vBeanList.size(); index++) {
    ValueBean vBean = vBeanList.get(index);
    String tdStyle = "";
%>

  <br>
  <a class="collapsed" id="ValueId" href="javascript:toggleValue()">+ Value Code <%=vBean.getValueCode()%></a>
  <table style = "display:none" class="normalTable" id="ValueTable">
  <col class="col1"/>
  <col class="col2"/>
  <col class="col3"/>
  <col class="col4"/>
  <tr>
    <td valign=top><%="Type"%></td>
    <td valign=top><%="Description"%></td>
    <td valign=top><%="Value"%></td>
    <td valign=top><%="Unit"%></td>
  </tr>
        <%
        for (ValueItem item: vBean.getValueSet()) {
        %>
           <tr>
           <td valign=top <%=tdStyle%>><%=item.getType()%></td>
           <td valign=top <%=tdStyle%>><%=item.getDescription()%></td>
           <td valign=top <%=tdStyle%>><%=item.getDisplayValue()%></td>
           <td valign=top <%=tdStyle%>><%=item.getUnit()%></td>
           </tr>
        <%
        }
        %>
  </table>

<% } %>

<% if (vBeanList.size()<=0) { %>
<i>(No value defined)</i>
<% } %>

<div id="blanketDiv" class="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>


function toggleValue()
{
var groupId =  '#ValueId';
var tableId =  '#ValueTable';
var domContent= $(groupId).text();
if($(groupId).hasClass('collapsed'))
  {
      $(groupId).removeClass('collapsed');
      $(groupId).addClass('expanded');
      $(groupId).text('-  ' + domContent.slice(1));
      $(tableId).removeAttr('style');
  }
else
  {
      $(groupId).removeClass('expanded');
      $(groupId).addClass('collapsed');
      $(groupId).text('+  ' + domContent.slice(1));
      $(tableId).attr('style', 'display:none');
  }
}
```

Comment: You are creating multiple items with the same ID, `"ValueId"`. How do you expect `$(groupId)` to know which one of those multiples you mean? (In practice, it will always select the first, as you've found.) You need to use the `this` keyword to refer to the element that the event just occurred on, and use DOM navigation methods (e.g., `.next()`) to figure out which table you need to update.

Comment: ah, straightforward, thanks for the help!